# NGiNX - redirect to https is unable to rewrite/replace correct wildcard char by originally requested sub-domain

Tags: http, ssl, nginx, https, ssl-certificate

I am using `NGiNX` server for one of my `application`.

my application **domain** is, `example.com`

I have a kind of requirement to ***generate sub-domain on the fly bases***.

so that I have configured NGiNX something likewise in order to fulfil the sub-domain(business) requirements.

***My NGiNX configure is likewise,***

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.example.com;
    #access_log      off;
.....
    location / {
      # redirect to secure site
      return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri; # Here it's redirecting me along with * only instead of sub-domain name
    }
.....
```

}

The above mentioned configuration working *perfectly* but that's for `HTTP` not for `HTTPS`.

I am reviewing the following things,

My **expected** URL is, `https://today.example.com` after successfully redirection happen to a secure(301) channel.

It's Redirecting me to here, `https://%2A.example.com/abc?abc=xyz (%2A is *, looks encoding scheme rewrite * -> %2A instead of today)`

**Instead of** it, it should be  `https://today.example.com/abc?abc=xyz`

**So, how to overcome on this handling *(wildcard char) in order to redirect successfully.**

***Any help would really appreciable !!***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `$host` and not `$server_name` in the redirect statement. `$server_name` is the name configured in nginx, i.e. `*.example.com`. `$host` is instead the name as used by the client to reach the server and which was given inside an absolute URI or the `Host` header, i.e. `today.example.com`:

```
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

Comment: Not working by following changes, rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$host$request_uri permanent;

could you please help me by providing exact hint.

Comment: @vishalgajera: it works perfectly for me in the redirect you have in your question, i.e. `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;`. I'm using it myself this way.